# Setting and changing build systems in Sublime Text 2

Tags: build, sublimetext2

How can I edit all the build systems so as to delete some ones or to change others ? Indeed I have added a personal build but it does not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build systems are located in `.sublime-build` files in subdirectories of the `Packages` directory, which can be located by going to `Preferences -> Browse Packages`. For example, the Python build system is in `Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build`.

If you're having problems, [the unofficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) and [the reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) should provide some assistance.

Comment: Thanks, that's the first day I use this editor. I'm already in love... ;-)

Comment: There is a lot of things, all I'm looking for at this moment. Great !